# How to receive PayPal payments from customers who wish to make payments towards a larger amount by a set date. They can pay any amount they wish

Tags: paypal, payment

I offer a service 2 times a year. Some of my clients desire to make payments rather than pay in one lump sum. They need to choose the amount they desire to pay and when they (date) they want to pay on. I just need PayPal for the processing and also the tracking for the amount they have paid. It also needs to not accept any more funds once they have reached the set amount.

Has anyone heard of this capability?

You time and consideration.

Comment: Your question lacks specifics. How many times a year will they be paying, and will they be present? It appears you may be asking for a recurring payment solution, perhaps one that bills twice a year for two exact amounts, or perhaps more, but your question is lacking in detail about your needs and about what exactly you mean by "tracking the amount they have paid".

Perhaps you need something as simple as a PayPal Subscribe button, which you can create in www.paypal.com/buttons and then change the image to suite your needs

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-pro/

They implement payment by instalments on their end with Paypal Credit. I believe you will still receive the entire payment in one go, but the customer will have to pay it off to Paypal directly. Alternatively, you may be able to hack something with recurring payment, though you would need to cancel it once the total amount has been reached; it's definitely not meant for that.

Regardless, you are probably better off contacting paypal support for this, since this isn't really a programming specific question.